# SQL Server question stored procedure loops

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have to run multiple queries that are dependent on each other

```
select a from a ( result has multiple rows)
select b from b  ( result has multiple rows)
```

the for each row in that query i need to run this

```
select c from c where c.a=a amd c.b=b

 insert  c into d
```

kinda like:

```
select a from a ( result has multiple rows)
select b from b  ( result has multiple rows 
  for a in a
      for b in b
          select c from c where c.a=a amd c.b=b
          insert  c,a,b into d
```

is this possible to do as an stored procedure?

thank you

Comment: table a has multiple rows in the result and so as b

Comment: the final result should look like this
table d:
c,a,b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stored procedure? Sure.  Shoot, it's even possible in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO d (c)
  SELECT c FROM c WHERE c.a IN (SELECT a FROM a) AND c.b IN (SELECT b FROM b)
```

You can probably even do a little better with a join, but to write that I need to know more about how the tables relate.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can write this query without using any loops in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT
INTO    d
SELECT  c.*
FROM    a
CROSS JOIN
        b
JOIN    с
ON      c.a = a.id
        AND c.b = b.id
```